# Twig variable not available on extended page outside blocks?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have this situation:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% set isManager = (isAdmin or isAffiliateManager or app.user.isFinanceDepartment) %}

{% block content %}
[...](add some html if manager)
{% endblock %}

{% block css %}
(add some css if manager)
{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
(add some js if manager)
{% endblock %}
```

`isAdmin` and `isAffiliateManager` are declared in `base.html.twig`. I want to access `isManager` in all the blocks, without declaring it 3 times. Why isn't that possible?

---

Edit: simpler replication: https://twigfiddle.com/kcz6mn/2

Comment: Hi, try moving your set variable on top of extends part.

Comment: @MuhFadjarRhomadoni same effect :(

Comment: I guess there is no solution, I'll calculate and pass isManager from the controller...

Comment: @DarkBee here it is: https://twigfiddle.com/kcz6mn/2 bar is set in main.twig, which is extended

Comment: If you need this on multiple places you could always extend twig and add a custom function which provides the check